# How do I get gdb to ignore my shell window's size?

Tags: linux, gdb

This is part of our unit test flow. I run gdb with the --command option to have it execute commands from a text file. The output of gdb is then directed into a file, and that file is compared to a reference file. But the problem is, gdb uses the current shell window's size to place newlines in its output. If the window is smaller, it will add more newlines to the output to make it more readable.

Is there an option in gdb to disable this, so that my test's output is always the same regardless of the shell window I run it in?

Edit: found it, I just use this as the first gdb command:

```
set width 80
```

Sometimes things are easy.

Comment: You probably want to make an actual answer for that solution. This way it is possible to separately vote for the question and the answer. Also, having a separate answer (with an up vote) allows the question to be removed from the unanswered list.

Comment: Yeah, much better. Remember to revert the question so it doesn't contain the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I just use this as the first gdb command:

```
set width 80
```

Sometimes things are easy.